# PowerShell WinSCP FTP script is downloading cached file for only 1 out of 8 files

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have a PowerShell script that downloads the most recent files of particular file extensions. The FTP directory has hundreds of hourly time-stamped files (mmddhh) in it that it clears out at the end of each hour. Each file has a unique extension. I am downloading files every hour for extensions `.tn1`, `.tn2`, `.tn3`, `.tn4`, `.tn5`, `.ky1`, and `.nc1`.

The file gets saved locally as `extension.txt` (e.g., `tn1.txt`, `tn2.txt`, etc).

The problem I'm having is that the `tn5` file that gets downloaded has a creation date of December of 2015 but on the server it is current (Apr 2016).

I have already set my IE options to 'check for newer versions of stored pages" "every time I visit the webpage".

I'm executing the script from VBA:

```vb
Shell("powershell ""H:\Worksheets\FTP\FTP.ps1""", vbHide)
```

```powershell
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
    $localPath = "H:\Worksheets\FTP"
    $remotePath = "/outgoing/data/LatestData/"
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
    $sessionOptions.HostName = 
    $sessionOptions.UserName = 
    $sessionOptions.Password = 

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Get list of files in the directory
        $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

        # Select the most recent file
        $latest = $directoryInfo.Files |
            Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory} |
            Where-Object {
                [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -eq ".nc1" -or
                [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -eq ".ky1" -or
                [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -like ".tn*" }

        Group-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) } | 
            ForEach-Object{ 
                $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
            }

        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($latest.Name)
        "GetExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'" -f $fileName, $extension 

        if ($latest -eq $Null)
        {
            Write-Host "No file found"
            exit 1
        }

        $latest | ForEach-Object{
            $extension = ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name)).Trim(".")
            $sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name)
            $session.GetFiles($sourcePath, "$localPath\$extension.txt" ).Check()
        }

        $stamp = $(Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm")
        $filename = $stamp.subString(0,$stamp.length-6)
        $session.GetFiles(
            ($remotePath + $fileName),
            ($localPath + $fileName + "." + $stamp)).Check()
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Set `Session.SessionLogFile` and append a log showing download of the `tn5` file.

Comment: The title says *"cached file for only 1 out of 8 files"*, while the text says *"has a creation date of December of 2015"*. It's not clear if the problem is just the timestamp or if also a content of the file is old. If the latter, can you download an up to date version of the file using any (GUI) FTP client?

Comment: The timestamp and the content of the file are old, leading me to believe my computer or perhaps the server that hosts my "H" drive is loading a cached version of the file. I will work on getting a log.

Comment: Did you try to download the file elsewhere?

Comment: I just used the WINSCP GUI to download it exactly as my script would and it worked perfectly. Then I deleted the file and ran the powershell script from powershell and it worked. I deleted the file again.

Finally, I invoked the script using VBA and it downloaded the correct file but a second later it got replaced by the older version of the file! I watched it happen. Weird.

Comment: Ok. So did you try other drive? C:?

Comment: Yes the C drive worked, it didn't revert to an older version of the file. I would just rename the file as it downloads to something like TN51.txt but I have no idea how to change my script to do that. Maybe I will just move all the files into a subfolder, I will have to update all the links I have to these files if I do that though. :/

Comment: So the problem is obviously not with your code, but with the drive. Why do you think that downloading to `TN51.txt` would mitigate the problem?

Comment: It has to be loading a cached version of that particular file so if I save it under a new name, that old cached tn5 file shouldn't get loaded over top of it.

Comment: Well I just tried downloading the files to a brand new subfolder on the network drive and it reverted the file to the old one when I called the script from VBA. This is bizarre.

I still can't make sense of the fact that if I run the script by right clicking it, it works fine, but if I invoke the script within visual basic it loads the cached file.

Comment: I figured out the problem. My vba script was calling a second script for a different ftp folder that happened to have an old tn5 file in it. So it was saving that over the tn5 from the other ftp folder. Wow. Thanks for helping me think this through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target file name is specified by the second argument of the `GetFiles` method call, i.e. the `"$localPath\$extension.txt"` in the:

```
$sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name)
$session.GetFiles($sourcePath, "$localPath\$extension.txt").Check()
```

If you want to append a "1" to the basename, use `"$localPath\${extension}1.txt"`:

```
$sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name)
$session.GetFiles($sourcePath, "$localPath\${extension}1.txt").Check()
```